# Switching between two components in React

Tags: reactjs

```
  rotateRender() {

    if(false) {

      return(
        <TimerPage></TimerPage>
      );


    } else {


      return(
        <RepoPage></RepoPage>
      );

    }
  }
```

I have two components called `TimerPage` and `RepoPage`. 
I created a simple conditional render function as above, but cannot come up with a condition to make it render iteratively after a certain amount of time.

For example, I first want to render `RepoPage` and switch to `TimerPage` after 5 minutes and then stay in `TimerPage` for 15 mins before I switch again to the `RepoPage`.

Any way to do this?

Comment: The setTImeout function is probably going to be the best way to make this happen

Comment: Use the parent components to render this component. And setup timer function which manipulate state of the parent components, resulting in re rendering the components. Your if condition should check that state changes via props and return required results in render()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Might not be that elegant, but this works</s>

Actually I was thinking that this block might be more elegant than the first one

```
const FIRST_PAGE = '5_SECONDS';
const SECOND_PAGE = '15_SECONDS';

const FirstComponent = () => (
  <div>5 SECONDS</div>
);

const SecondComponent = () => (
  <div>15 SECONDS</div>
);

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    currentPage: FIRST_PAGE
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const {currentPage} = this.state;
    const isFirst = currentPage === FIRST_PAGE;

    if (isFirst) {
      this._showSecondPageDelayed();
    } else {
      this._showFirstPageDelayed();
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._showSecondPageDelayed();
  };

  _showSecondPageDelayed = () => setTimeout(() => {this.setState({currentPage: SECOND_PAGE})}, 5000);

  _showFirstPageDelayed = () => setTimeout(() => {this.setState({currentPage: FIRST_PAGE})}, 15000);

  render() {
    const {currentPage} = this.state;
    const isFirst = currentPage === FIRST_PAGE;
    const ComponentToRender =  isFirst ? FirstComponent : SecondComponent;

    return <ComponentToRender/>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment section, you can create a higher order component that will cycle through your components based on the state of that component. Use setTimeout to handle the timer logic for the component.

```
state = {
  timer: true
}

componentDidMount = () => {
  setInterval(
    () => {
    this.setState({ timer: !this.state.timer })
  }, 30000)
}

render(){
  const {timer} = this.state
  if(timer){
    return <TimerPage />
  } else {
    return <RepoPage />
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Changed setTimeout to setInterval so that it will loop every 5 minutes instead of just calling setState once

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new context API to achieve this. The benefit is now I have a configurable, reusable provider to play with throughout my application. Here is a quick demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/k2vvy54r8o

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const ThemeContext = createContext({ alternativeTheme: false });

class ThemeWrapper extends Component {
  state = {
    alternativeTheme: false
  };

  themeInterval = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.themeInterval = setInterval(
      () =>
        this.setState(({ alternativeTheme }) => ({
          alternativeTheme: !alternativeTheme
        })),
      this.props.intervalLength
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.themeInterval) {
      clearInterval(this.themeInterval);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <ThemeWrapper intervalLength={2000}>
    <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {({ alternativeTheme }) =>
        alternativeTheme ? <p>Alternative Theme</p> : <p>Common Theme</p>
      }
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
  </ThemeWrapper>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Whatever you do make sure on componentWillUnmount to clear your interval or timeout to avoid a memory leak.